# run for loop a few times inside while loop python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
start = 0
end = 100

file = open("numbers.txt", "r")

while start <= end:
    for x in file.readlines():
        print(x)
        print(start)
    start += 1
```

Why does the For Loop only run once inside the While Loop?

I want to turn on For Loop whenever the [start += 1] is increased ..

Comment: After reading *everything* from the file, there's kinda not much left in it.

Comment: `file.readline()` instead of `file.readlines()`?

Comment: may i know what purpose you are using while loop? and  i think while loop is enough for reading text from file.

Comment: I want to re-read the file many times

Comment: readline() => read a letter letter from the file. I want to read the file line by line

Comment: Try out my answer posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first run `open("numbers.txt")`, a pointer pointing to the first char in the file is created. At the end of the for loop, the pointer is at the end of the file and further iterations of the while loop will not reset the pointer's position to the start by default. Hence you have to call file.seek(0) to bring the pointer back to its starting position before the next iteration

```
start = 0
end = 100

file = open("numbers.txt", "r")

while start <= end:
    for x in file.readlines():
        print(x)
        print(start)
    start += 1
    file.seek(0)

file.close()
```

Also, it is a good practice to run file.close() when it is no longer needed so I have included it in as well